# Timing Discontinuity with Replace[] Function

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, timing

When constructing certain square matrices I noticed a sharp jump in the time required to build them. I've included code and a plot of time required to make the matrix vs dimensionality of the matrix. As soon as the matrix becomes $90\times 90$ there is a seven-fold increase in the time required build it. Seeing as I'm just using replacement rules, I can't understand why there would be such a jump. Does anyone have any ideas as to what's so important about the matrix being $90\times 90$?

EDIT: On a closer inspection it appears that this behavior occurs even with just the `Array[]` part of this code, though the "jump" is not as
clean.

```
lilmatmaker[emm_, Vval_, Wval_, nua_, nub_] := (
  blank = DiagonalMatrix[Table[k + emm, {k, emm, 1, -1}]];(* 
  Makes the diagonal part of the matrix and pads the rest out with \
0s. *)
  
  Do[blank = 
    ReplacePart[blank, {k + 1, k + 2} -> nua - nub - nua*nub*k], {k, 
    1, emm - 1}]; (* Adds one off-diagonal *)
  
  Do[blank = 
    ReplacePart[
     blank, {k + 2, k + 1} -> Vval*Wval (nua - k + nub)], {k, 1, 
    emm - 1}]; (* Adds the other off-diagonal*)
  )
maxM = 200;
timelist = {};
Do[(
  V = RandomReal[{0, 10}];
  W = V*RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
  nooa = RandomInteger[];
  noob = RandomInteger[];
  AppendTo[
   timelist, {M, Timing[lilmatmaker[M, V, W, nooa, noob]][[1]]}]
  ), {M, 1, maxM}]
ListPlot[timelist, Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Dimensionality of Matrix", "Time (s)"}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Plot of the time required]

Comment: Interesting! My guess is that it changes how it allocates memory, but I don't know. Also, do you realize you're attempting to replace a part outside the array (when `k` is `emm - 1`, the part referred to by e.g. the first `Do` loop is `{emm, emm + 1}`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here, from what I can tell.

First, my guess is that at some level, somehow, it has something to do with the fact that we suddenly need more bits to represent all the spots in the matrix. Note that the first "high" value is at $91 \times 91$, and $\log_2(90^2) < 13$ whereas $\log_2(91^2) > 13$. I imagine this has to do with some fundamental cutoff, especially since this shows up even when using constant sparse arrays. I don't know anything more about this part of things, and I hope someone with a better knowledge of Mathematica's internals can chime in.

The second thing going on has to do with how `Timing` works. From the docs:

> On certain computer systems with multiple CPUs, the Wolfram Language kernel may sometimes spawn additional threads on different CPUs. On some operating systems, `Timing` may ignore these additional threads. On other operating systems, it may give the total time spent in all threads, which may exceed the result from `AbsoluteTiming`.

Indeed, if we use `AbsoluteTiming` instead of `Timing`, the jump disappears! My guess is that when the matrices get large enough, Mathematica decides to use some more cores at once, and then `Timing` adds all this time up. Note that we do see some upwards variability after the $91\times91$ mark even in `AbsoluteTiming`, which I'm guessing is due to the added cost of splitting up tasks between cores.

[image: Graph comparing Timing and AbsoluteTiming]

---

But as a bonus, since you seem concerned about timing, I thought I'd mention that there's a lot you can do to speed up your code! You might benefit from constructing `SparseArrays` via `Band` instead of using `Do` loops (or at least building your matrix all at once somehow, rather than overwriting the same variable multiple times); as a rule of thumb `Do` loops are slower than more functional approaches that manipulate "all the data at once". Generally you'll want to [avoid procedural loops in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396)!

`SparseArrays` are also better here because they let us build the matrix in linear(-ish) time and memory as opposed to quadratic(-ish).

(It's also generally better style to build a function that evaluates to the thing you're creating rather than assign a variable to it, but of course there are applications where you'll want to do the latter, and this is more of a personal preference anyway.)

Here's how you'd do that. But first, note that you currently attempt to replace parts that lie outside of your array: namely `{emm, emm + 1}` and `{emm + 1, emm}` at the ends of the second and third `Do` loops. I'm assuming in the following that you actually meant to replace the part at `{k, k+1}` instead of at `{k+1, k+2}`, since otherwise you miss a replacement, and I changed the code to reflect that. But if this isn't right, you might want to adapt things.

Note that we need a special case for `emm == 1`. We also use `Range` and the fact that arithmetic operations distribute over lists (due to being `Listable`). Depending on how you resolve that off-by-one error, you might want to change `Range[emm-1]` to `Range[0,emm-2]`.

My function evaluates to the `SparseArray` and does not set `blank` to it, but to make sure we're measuring the right thing, I assign `blank` to it inside the benchmarking functions.

Here's a block of code starting with the more optimized version thanks to `SparseArray`; the rest just modifies your original graph-creating code as needed to show the difference.

```
lilmatmaker2[1, _, _, _, _] := {{2}}
lilmatmaker2[emm_ /; emm >= 2, Vval_, Wval_, nua_, nub_] := 
 SparseArray[{
   Band[{1, 1}] -> Range[2 emm, emm + 1, -1], 
   Band[{1, 2}] -> nua - nub - nua*nub*Range[emm - 1], 
   Band[{2, 1}] -> Vval*Wval (nua - Range[emm - 1] + nub)
  }, {emm, emm}]

(* lilmatmaker with second do loops changed: *)

lilmatmaker[emm_, Vval_, Wval_, nua_, nub_] := (blank = 
   DiagonalMatrix[Table[k + emm, {k, emm, 1, -1}]];
(*Makes the diagonal part of the matrix and pads the \
rest out with 0s.*)
  Do[blank = 
    ReplacePart[blank, {k, k + 1} -> nua - nub - nua*nub*k], {k, 1, 
    emm - 1}];(*Adds one off-diagonal*)
  Do[blank = 
    ReplacePart[blank, {k + 1, k} -> Vval*Wval (nua - k + nub)], {k, 
    1, emm - 1}];(*Adds the other off-diagonal*))
(*Adds the other off-diagonal*)

maxM = 200;
timelist = {};
timelist2 = {};
abstimelist = {};
abstimelist2 = {};
memlist = {};
memlist2 = {};


Do[(V = RandomReal[{0, 10}];
  W = V*RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
  nooa = RandomInteger[];
  noob = RandomInteger[];
  
  (* Check equality: *)
  If[lilmatmaker[M, V, W, nooa, noob];
    ! TrueQ[blank == lilmatmaker2[M, V, W, nooa, noob]],
    Throw[{$Failed, blank, lilmatmaker2[M, V, W, nooa, noob]}]];

  Clear[blank];
  AppendTo[timelist, {M, Timing[lilmatmaker[M, V, W, nooa, noob]][[1]]}];
  Clear[blank];
  AppendTo[timelist2, {M, 
    Timing[blank = lilmatmaker2[M, V, W, nooa, noob]][[1]]}];
  Clear[blank];
  AppendTo[abstimelist, {M, 
    AbsoluteTiming[lilmatmaker[M, V, W, nooa, noob]][[1]]}];
  Clear[blank];
  AppendTo[abstimelist2, {M, 
    AbsoluteTiming[blank = lilmatmaker2[M, V, W, nooa, noob]][[1]]}];
  Clear[blank];
  AppendTo[memlist, {M, MaxMemoryUsed[lilmatmaker[M, V, W, nooa, noob]]}];
  Clear[blank];
  AppendTo[memlist2, {M, 
    MaxMemoryUsed[blank = lilmatmaker2[M, V, W, nooa, noob]]}];
  ), {M, 1, maxM}]

ListPlot[{timelist, timelist2, abstimelist, abstimelist2}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Dimensionality of Matrix", "Time (s)"}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLabels -> {"lilmatmaker Timing", "lilmatmaker2 Timing", 
   "lilmatmaker AbsoluteTiming", "lilmatmaker2 AbsoluteTiming"}]
ListPlot[{memlist, memlist2}, Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Dimensionality of Matrix", "Max bytes used"},
 PlotLabels -> {"lilmatmaker", "lilmatmaker2"}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Timing]
[image: Bytes used]

And if you change `maxM` to `800` and wait a while, the speed difference becomes quite dramatic! Here I use just absolute timing. `SparseArrays` can be very helpful!

[image: maxM 800 absolute timing difference]

If your arrays *aren't* sparse, `Array` is generally your best bet, and can be a lot faster than a `Do` loop to modify parts.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think I love you.